# IE not showing website font

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

I have Trebutchet MS ttf font on my website.

Import file looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Trebuchet-MS";
  src: url('../fonts/Trebuchet-MS-Regular.ttf');
  font-weight: 500;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Trebuchet-MS";
  src: url('../fonts/Trebuchet-MS-Bold.ttf');
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

It's working perfect on google chrome and mozilla, but not working on IE.

Any sugesstion to my problem?

Comment: which version of IE? All modern browsers including IE9 and up support `woff`, which is a wrapper around opentype fonts that makes them explicit "for the web", unlike using a bare `ttf` or `otf`, which is a universal system font and guaranteed rejected by all versions of IE except under very specific opentype metadata settings. **However:** Trubechet is not free to distribute or use as webfont unless you payed $100+ for a webfont license. (Just because it came with your computer doesn't make it free to redistribute at all)

Comment: Note that ttf is an uncompressed format and not suitable for websites. Use woff or eot instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "GothamBook";
    src: url("../fonts/Gotham-Book.eot");
    src: url(".../fonts/Gotham-Book.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/Gotham-Book.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("../fonts/Gotham-Book.ttf") format("truetype"), 
    url("../fonts/Gotham-Book.svg#Gotham-Book") format("svg");
}
```

this code fixed the issue

Comment: This code is 2012 code, and insane in 2016 =) All modern browsers support `woff`, and you don't need any of the other formates: `eot` isn't supported by MS anymore, `svg` does not even **exist** anymore as a font spec (almost all browsers removed support again), and `ttf`/`otf` are universal system fonts, which need to pass way stricter parsing than their `woff` counterpart.